# Specifying local install directory for ./configure for pango-1.32.6

Tags: compiling, software-installation, configure

I have built `cairo-1.7.6` for use in building `pango-1.32.6`, and I have installed it to a directory in my home directory: `/home/me/local/cairo-1.7.6`. Under this directory are the expected `include`, `lib` and `share` directories.

However, I don't seem to be able to get the pango `./configure` to suck in the cairo dependency from that directory. I have tried setting the `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` to the relevant directories, and I have looking in `./configure --help` but none of the options seem obviously related.

Is there a general way to pass a locally installed library's paths to a `configure` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /home/me/local/cairo-1.7.6/lib
then try ./configure --prefix=/home/me/local/pango-1.32.6

Comment: Looks like it was also the pkgconfig directories that were missing: `/home/me/local/harfbuzz-0.9.15/lib/pkgconfig`, which then caused cairo to fail to load. I changed to `--prefix=/home/me/local/gtkbuild` for all the deps for the build and then `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/me/local/gtkbuild/lib/pkgconfig` to find this "merged" directory.